# Django get attribute from urls into filter

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Hi I'm new to django and i'm trying to make a website that provides series with seasons and episodes.

I successfully created the CreateView for the Serie. Now i'm about to do the CreateView for the Season. It should look something like this.

Seasons:
[1] [2] [3] [add]

If you click add it should show a modal with the form for the season. My code looks like this:

**models.py**

```
class Serie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=serie_dir_path)
    ...


class Season(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    serie = models.ForeignKey(Serie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    episode = models.FileField(upload_to=episode_dir_path)
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('library', LibListView.as_view(), name='library'),
    path('series/<int:pk>/season/<int:order>', SeriesDetailView.as_view(), name='serie-detail'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class SeasonCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Season
    fields = ['order']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SeasonCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'serie': Serie.objects.filter()
        })
        return context
```

**season_form.html**

```
{% for season in serie.season_set.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

What do I have to write into the filter() that I get the Serie from the url?

Comment: Why would you think this would work? Where is `serie` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Sorry i've got no idea. As I said I'm new to django and I'm just trying around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it myself. I used `get_object_or_404`

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    s = get_object_or_404(Serie, id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    context = super(SeasonCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'serie': s
    })
    return context
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting parameter from url:

```
parameter = request.GET.get("parameter_name")
```

Filtering it:

```
'serie': Serie.objects.filter(model_field_name=parameter)
```

Comment: I tried it like the following but it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong? 
`parameter = self.request.GET.get("pk")`
`'serie': Serie.objects.filter(id=parameter)`

Comment: Both lines are in `the get_context_data` def

Comment: No error message. It just doesn't show any seasons ^^

Comment: ok. the easiest way i think is to check what is empty try sth like this:
`print("parameter: "+self.request.GET.get("pk"))`
`print("query: "+Serie.objects.filter(id=parameter))`

and check the console :)

Comment: and use `pk` instead of `id` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193142/discussion-between-janik-spies-and-michael-stachura).

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for season in serie.season_set.all %}

<p>{season}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Please try **all()** instead of **all** in for loop definition.

Comment: you can't use `()` to make a function call in a Django template, the OP's syntax is correct for calling `.all()` on the query set